# Given 2^n, find n using logarithm

Tags: c, math

Given a integer(2^n) which is power of 2, I want to find out n, the index value using logarithm. The formula to find index is : log(number) / log(2). Following is the code snippet :

```
  unsigned long int a;
  double apower;
  apower = log((double)a) / log((double)2);
```

I found that value of 'apower' is wrong at some large value of a, I do not know the value, as my code fails, after I submit it. Why is it so? Is there some casting issue?

Following is the entire snippet :

```
  int count = 0;
  unsigned long int a,b;
  double apower,bpower;
  apower = log((double)a) / log((double)2);
  bpower = log((double)b) / log((double)2);
  count = abs(apower - bpower);
  printf("%d\n",count);
```

Values of a and b will always be power of 2. So apower and bpower must be have 00 in decimal places. That is why, value of count will be int (%d).
I just want to know the behavior of Logarithm.

Comment: why do you use `unsigned long int` for `a` if you cast it to `double` anyways? That makes no sense...

Comment: What is sizeof(long) on your platform?

Comment: ive written a small testprogram utilizing your code. it works until the `n` gets to big for `unsigned long int`, when too large, the result is `-inf`, which is correct behavious. So please provide more informations on your homework...sorry...your problem...

Comment: Count trailing zeros? There's compiler intrinsics for that. on gcc, it's `__builtin_ctz()` or for `long`: `__builtin_ctzl()`, `long long`: `__builtin_ctzll()`. Other compilers may have equivalents.

Comment: @Nidhoegger: If the integers are powers of 2, it is possible to convert them to doubles (or even floats) without loss

Comment: The input is 10^17, so i used, unsigned long int

Comment: I know that it is possible @StefanHaustein, but it makes just no sense to use an `ìnt` only for the purpose of casting o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `double` math, the log result or quotient may not be exactly the mathematical result but 1 (or 2) next representable `double` away.

Calculating `log()` only returns an exact mathematical result for `log(0)`, all other mathematical results are irrational.  All `double` are rational.

This may result in an answer like 29.999999..., which saved as an `int` is 29.

Recommend using integer math instead

---

```
int mylog2(unsigned long x) {
  int y = 0;
  #if (ULONG_MAX>>16 > 1lu<<16)
    if (x >= 1lu<<32) { x >>= 32; y += 32;
  #endif
  if (x >= 1lu<<16) { x >>= 16; y += 16; }
  if (x >= 1lu<<8) { x >>= 8; y += 8; }
  if (x >= 1lu<<4) { x >>= 4; y += 4; }
  if (x >= 1lu<<2) { x >>= 2; y += 2; }
  if (x >= 1lu<<1) { x >>= 1; y += 1; }
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am only answering half of your question, because it is not necessary to use logs to solve this. An easy way is to use this:

```
unsigned long long a = 0x8000000000000000ULL;
int n = 0;
while (a >>= 1) n++;
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Output:

```
63
```

Converting to logs and divding may cause loss of significance, in which case you should use `round`. You use the word "submit", so it was an online challenge that failed? What exactly did you print? (in this case) `63.000000`? That would be got from the default format of `%f`.

Comment: [faster way to compute the log of an integer](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog)

Comment: i wanted to avoid loops, so that result comes in O(1).

Answer (score 4):

Why not take advantage of the fact that the log2 is stored in the exponent field of a double? :)

```
unsigned long long a = 0x8000000000000000ULL;
union {
  double d;
  unsigned long long l;
} u;
u.d = a;
int apower = (u.l >> 52) - 1023;
printf("%d\n", apower);
```

Output:

```
63
```

This assumes that unsigned long longs and doubles are 64 bit and that the input is > 0.

Comment: @EOF: Didn't mean this too serious, but haven't seen this in the gazillion of other log2 questions out here on stack overflow, and I always wanted to try this :)

Comment: Addressed in the fine print O:)

Comment: The `frexp` function makes it possible to do this in a portable way.

Comment: Doesn't this produce troubles if you have denormalized floating point numbers, I.e. numbers that small/close to zero that they can't be stored in normalized form?

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer The question says "Given a integer(2^n) which is power of 2"